# Compile Error, Sub or Function not defined

Tags: function, excel, vba

trying to create my first UDF, I keep getting Compile error: Sub or Function not defined. completely self taught, trying this out as a hobby. I get the first line highlighted on this error, here's my code.

```
Function SkillCost(AttrLVL, SkillLVL, E_A_H)
 If E_A_H = "E" Then
  If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < 0 Then
   SkillCost = 0
  Else
   If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < 1 Then
    SkillCost = 1
   Else
    If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < 2 Then
     SkillCost = 2
    Else
     Skill Cost = ((SkillLVL - AttrLVL) - 1) * 4
    End If
   End If
  End If
 Else
  If E_A_H = "A" Then
   If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < -1 Then
    SkillCost = 0
   Else
    If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < 0 Then
     SkillCost = 1
    Else
     If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < 1 Then
      SkillCost = 2
     Else
      SkillCost = (SkillLVL - AttrLVL) * 4
     End If
    End If
   End If
  Else
   If E_A_H = "H" Then
    If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < -2 Then
     SkillCost = 0
    Else
     If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < -1 Then
      SkillCost = 1
     Else
      If SkillLVL - AttrLVL < 0 Then
       SkillCost = 2
      Else
       SkillCost = ((SkillLVL - AttrLVL) + 1) * 4
      End If
     End If
    End If
   End If
  End If
 End If
End Function
```

I know this is just a bunch of nested if()'s, but I wanted to start with something simple, and I would be doing this within vlookup()'s. Here's the chart I'm basing this off of. [What my function is quantifying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uNdG.png) basically, just figuring out skill level cost when presented with defining attribute lvl, desired skill lvl, and difficulty of skill.

Comment: Look into `Select Case` It would make this a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling error here:

```
 Skill Cost = ((SkillLVL - AttrLVL) - 1) * 4
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment look into `Select Case`:

```
Function SkillCost(AttrLVL, SkillLVL, E_A_H)
 If E_A_H = "E" Then
    Select Case SkillLVL - AttrLVL
        Case Is < 0
            SkillCost = 0
        Case Is < 1
            SkillCost = 1
        Case Is < 2
            SkillCost = 2
        Case Else
            SkillCost = ((SkillLVL - AttrLVL) - 1) * 4
    End Select
 ElseIf E_A_H = "A" Then
    Select Case SkillLVL - AttrLVL
        Case Is < -1
            SkillCost = 0
        Case Is < 0
            SkillCost = 1
        Case Is < 1
            SkillCost = 2
        Case Else
            SkillCost = ((SkillLVL - AttrLVL) - 1) * 4
    End Select
ElseIf E_A_H = "H" Then
    Select Case SkillLVL - AttrLVL
        Case Is < -2
            SkillCost = 0
        Case Is < -1
            SkillCost = 1
        Case Is < 0
            SkillCost = 2
        Case Else
            SkillCost = ((SkillLVL - AttrLVL) - 1) * 4
    End Select
End If
End Function
```

This is just here for reference.  @Gary'sStudent pointed out the error.